# langchain.schema.output_parser.OutputParserException: Got invalid JSON object. Error: Extra data: line 7 column 1 (char 1406)

Tags: parsing, langchain, large-language-model

I am getting intermittent  json parsing error for output of string of chain.run() for the code snippet below

**Outline of the python function that queries LLM:-**

```
    output_parser = StructuredOutputParser.from_response_schemas(response_schemas)
    format_instructions = output_parser.get_format_instructions()
```

```
template = """
Create a NIFI pipeline using standard NIFI processors. You can use a custom NIFI processor    only if it fits to the  examples given below. 
format the output as JSON with the following keys: pipelineDesription implementationSteps processorList connectorList """
```

```
prompt_template = PromptTemplate(input_variables=["question"], template=template, partial_variables={"format_instructions": format_instructions})
prompt_template.format(question=input_qa)
chain= LLMChain(llm=llm,prompt=prompt_template)
answer=chain.run( input_qa)
output_dict = output_parser.parse(answer)   =>   ERROR here
```

**Error Details:-**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GenAI\adaptercopilot\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\output_parsers\json.py", line 86, in parse_and_check_json_markdown
    json_obj = parse_json_markdown(text)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\GenAI\adaptercopilot\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\output_parsers\json.py", line 68, in parse_json_markdown        
    parsed = json.loads(json_str)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\json\__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\python\Lib\json\decoder.py", line 340, in decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Extra data", s, end)
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 7 column 1 (char 1406)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\GenAI\adaptercopilot\Test.py", line 90, in <module>
    answer=(qaDataFlow(question))
            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\GenAI\adaptercopilot\adapterLLMModule\LLMModule.py", line 215, in qaDataFlow
    output_dict = output_parser.parse(answer)
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\GenAI\adaptercopilot\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\output_parsers\structured.py", line 95, in parse
    return parse_and_check_json_markdown(text, expected_keys)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "D:\GenAI\adaptercopilot\venv\Lib\site-packages\langchain\output_parsers\json.py", line 88, in parse_and_check_json_markdolangchain.schema.output_parser.OutputParserException: Got invalid JSON object. Error: Extra data: line 7 column 1 (char 1406)
```

When i inspect the answer= chain.run(input_qa),  for a successful case print(answer) gives

```json
{
......
}
```
While for unsuccessful case it print(answer) gives
```json
{
......
}
```
\n``` This is marked has extra data while parsing.

Answer (score 1):

I found a temporary fix to this problem. The markdown structure that is receive d as answer has correct  format ```json { .....} ```

What i found is  this format changes with extra character as
```json {......}```\n``` intermittently. Not sure if this problem is coming from LLM or langchain. But i see multiple people have raised in github and so solution is presented.

By introducing below code, json parsing works.

```
print(answer)
if answer.find("\`\`\`\n\`\`\`") != -1:
   answer = answer.replace("\`\`\`\n\`\`\`", "\`\`\`")
   print("Found and replaced")
```